# Android Swipe up and Down to hide button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

How does swipe app and swipe down implemented in google+ I need to add something in my Fragments. Any Ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 solutions for you:

1. https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView You can customise the footer view.
2. You can do it yourself. Trigger onScrollListener of Listview or Gridview

   ```
       listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

       @Override
       public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {


           if (view.getId() == listview.getId()) {
               final int currentFirstVisibleItem = mGrid.getFirstVisiblePosition();
               if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                   Log.i("a", "scrolling down...");
                   if (mIsScrollingUp) {
                       mIsScrollingUp = false;
                       bottomView.setTranslationY(bottomHeight);
                   }
               } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                   Log.i("a", "scrolling up...");
                   if (!mIsScrollingUp) {
                       mIsScrollingUp = true;
                       bottomView.setTranslationY(0);
                   }
               }

               mLastFirstVisibleItem = currentFirstVisibleItem;
           }
   }
   ```

Let me know if my code is wrong